# Maximum MIME type length when storing the type in a database

Tags: database, mime-types

What are people using as the length of a [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) field in their databases? The longest one we've seen so far is 72 bytes:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

But I'm just waiting for a longer one. We're using 250 now, but has anyone seen a longer MIMEType than that?

---

#### Edit

From the accepted answer, 127 for type and sub-type each, so that's 254 max, plus the '/' is a limit of 255 for the combined value.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

According to RFC 4288 "Media Type Specifications and Registration Procedures", type (eg. "application") and subtype (eg "vnd...") both [can be max 127 characters](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4288#section-4.2). So including the slash, the maximum length is 255.

**Edit:** Meanwhile, that document has been obsoleted by [RFC 6838](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6838#section-4.2), which does not alter the maximum size but adds a remark:

> Also note that while this syntax allows names of up to 127
> characters, implementation limits may make such long names
> problematic. For this reason, `<type-name>` and `<subtype-name>` SHOULD
> be limited to 64 characters.

Comment: Damn, I'd searched for that and never could find a good reference.

Comment: For those who are not good at maths, that makes 127+1+127 = **255** if you include the slash.

Comment: Has anyone an example of a mime type that goes over 127 chars? I doubt there are much? At least I've never seen one and I don't think they're good in any way.

Comment: Math is not for programmers.

Comment: @burzum, this one has 54 cars `application/x-nokia-9000-communicator-add-on-software`, the fact is not that a MIME type with 255 chars exists, it's only about the specification of the RFC 4288 that fixes the max length to 255 chars, so the question "how long" is answered in a universal way.

Comment: The MIME type for `.pptx` files is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation` which has 73 characters. The subtype alone is 61 characters, which is very close to the limit mentioned in RFC 6838.

Comment: Today's longest entry in https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.pivotCacheDefinition+xml` (plus 2 more of the same length), which makes 11 + 1 + 72 (more than the suggested 64 subtype chars) = 84 chars.